# A future change in how things are seen - "will be seen" or "will have been seen"

Tags: grammar, perfect-constructions

I want to write a sentence which says that in the future current events at some point in time might start to be seen differently.

> It would be fun to know which events from the present **will be seen**
>   as milestones in the future.

or

> It would be fun to know which events from the present **will have been
>   seen** as milestones in the future.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. Meaning-wise, the first sentence is much more natural.

Answer (score 2):

"Will have been seen" is grammatically correct only if the vantage point is situated in the future, e.g., by the end of this year, the film will have been seen by x people.  For your purpose "will be seen" is more correct.